# Mule Kafka Consumer - Pattern matching to filter messages

Tags: mule, mule-component

I need to consume messages from Kafka topic in Mule API.  Publisher is going to publish millions of messages into the topic. Consumer should not be burdened to fetch each and do filter for its required messages. I wanted to know if we can get only the messages matching specific values from the topic based on any configurations in the consumer property file?

For Example:

Json message published to the topic will be:

```
{
"OrderId": "XXXXXX",
"Region": "XXX",
"Time":"",
"Date":"",
"Label":"",
"Type":"",
"Comment":"",
...
...
...
}
```

I need to get messages only from a list of Regions matching the second element in the message above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Consumer should not be burdened to fetch each and do filter

I don't believe it is possible. Something should parse the message and do the filtering. And that's the role of the flow.